# How to resolve non serialize exception?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I use this code, it runs fine:

```
val result = rdd.filter(row =>
  row.get[DateTime]("eventtime") > Offset._1 && 
  row.get[DateTime]("eventtime") <= Offset._2)
```

However, in case of a generalization of the code, I encounter a "task not serialize" exception.

The code :

```
def resultFilter(offsetValue: (Imports.DateTime, Imports.DateTime)) = (x:CassandraRow) => {
  val date = x.get[DateTime]("mytime")
  date > offsetValue._1 && date <= offsetValue._2
}
```

and its usage (throwing the error)

```
rdd.filter(resultFilter(offsetValue))
```

The output :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:166) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:158) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:1476) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.filter(RDD.scala:300) ~[spark-core_2.10-1.2.2.2.jar:1.2.2.2]
at com.aruba.sparkjobs.apprf.LeaderBoardJob.runJob(LeaderBoardJob.scala:203) ~[ee507b50-011f-42de-8bd5-536ca113d640-2015-09-25T11:11:23.637+05:30.jar:1.0.0-b.3]
```

How to serialize the above function?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30897104/task-not-serializable-exception

Comment: @Reactormonk, if you look at the answer to that question, I'm guessing it probably doesn't apply here!

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Most likely true.

Comment: @spk: Please indent code properly. 2. What is the return value of `resultFilter`, as it only creates a `val` `date` thus seems to go from CassandraRow => Unit3. How does the `Imports` object look like (code-wise)? I assume the error to be here.

Comment: @MartinSenne, you've been mislead by the bad formatting. See the edited version

Comment: Indeed. Still and as I still regard this as the problem: How is `Imports.DateTime` defined?

Comment: Yes, indeed.  We need a MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a wild guess that each of the `Imports.DateTime` objects in the tuple argument `offsetValue` have a reference to the (non-serializable) `Imports` object. If that's the case, then something like this will probably work:

```
def resultFilter(offsetValue: (Imports.DateTime, Imports.DateTime)) = {
  val offsetValue1 = offsetValue._1
  val offsetValue2 = offsetValue._2
  (x: CassandraRow) => {
    val date = x.get[DateTime]("mytime")
    date > offsetValue1 && date <= offsetValue2
  }
}
```